# How to enable coredns for dns discovery on kubernetes version 1.14?

Tags: kubernetes, kube-dns, coredns

I have a problem with service (DNS) discovery in **kubernetes 1.14** version in **ubuntu bionic**.

Right now my 2 pods communicating using IP addresses. How can I enable **coredns** for service (DNS) discovery?

Here is the output of kubectl for service and pods from kube-system namespace:

```
    kubectl get pods,svc --namespace=kube-system | grep dns
    pod/coredns-fb8b8dccf-6plz2          1/1     Running            0          6d23h
    pod/coredns-fb8b8dccf-thxh6          1/1     Running            0          6d23h
    
    service/kube-dns        ClusterIP   10.96.0.10       <none>        53/UDP,53/TCP,9153/TCP   6d23h
```

### I have installed kubernetes on master node(ubuntu bionic machine) using below steps

```
    apt-get update
    apt-get install     apt-transport-https     ca-certificates     curl     gnupg-agent     software-properties-common
    curl -fsSL https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu/gpg | apt-key add -
    add-apt-repository    "deb [arch=amd64] https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu $(lsb_release -cs) stable"
    apt-get update
    apt-get install docker-ce docker-ce-cli containerd.io
    apt-get update && apt-get install -y apt-transport-https curl
    curl -s https://packages.cloud.google.com/apt/doc/apt-key.gpg | apt-key add -
    
    cat <<EOF >/etc/apt/sources.list.d/kubernetes.list
    deb https://apt.kubernetes.io/ kubernetes-xenial main
    EOF
    
    apt-get update
    apt-get install -y kubelet kubeadm kubectl
    kubectl version
    apt-mark hold kubelet kubeadm kubectl
    kubeadm config images pull
    swapoff -a
    kubeadm init
    
    mkdir -p $HOME/.kube
    cp -i /etc/kubernetes/admin.conf $HOME/.kube/config
    chown $(id -u):$(id -g) $HOME/.kube/config
    sysctl net.bridge.bridge-nf-call-iptables=1
    kubectl apply -f "https://cloud.weave.works/k8s/net?k8s-version=$(kubectl version | base64 | tr -d '\n')"
    kubectl get pods --all-namespaces
```

#### This is on worker node

```
    Docker is already installed, so directly installing kubernetes on worker node
    apt-get update && apt-get install -y apt-transport-https curl
    curl -s https://packages.cloud.google.com/apt/doc/apt-key.gpg | apt-key add -
    cat <<EOF >/etc/apt/sources.list.d/kubernetes.list
    deb https://apt.kubernetes.io/ kubernetes-xenial main
    EOF
    
    apt-get update
    apt-get install -y kubelet kubeadm kubectl
    kubectl version
    apt-mark hold kubelet kubeadm kubectl
    swapoff -a
    Now joined worker node to master
```

### Answer:-

I think everything was setup correctly by default, There was a misunderstanding by me that I can call a server running in one pod from another pod using the container name and port which I have specified in spec, but instead I should use service name and port.

### Below is my deployment spec and service spec:-

#### Deployment spec:-

```
    apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
    kind: Deployment
    metadata:
      name: node-server1-deployment
    spec:
      replicas: 1
      template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: node-server1
    spec:
      hostname: node-server1
      containers:
      - name: node-server1
        image: bvenkatr/node-server1:1
        ports:
        - containerPort: 5551
```

#### Service spec:

```
    kind: Service
    apiVersion: v1
    metadata:
      name: node-server1-service
    spec:
      selector:
         app: node-server1
      ports:
      - protocol: TCP
        port: 5551
```

Comment: How did you install/deploy Kubernetes?

Comment: hi @coderanger I have updated my question with steps for installation of kubernetes on ubuntu bionic

Answer (score 1):

> As of Kubernetes v1.12, CoreDNS is the recommended DNS Server, replacing kube-dns. In Kubernetes, CoreDNS is installed with the following default Corefile configuration:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: coredns
  namespace: kube-system
data:
  Corefile: |
    .:53 {
        errors
        health
        kubernetes cluster.local in-addr.arpa ip6.arpa {
           pods insecure
           upstream
           fallthrough in-addr.arpa ip6.arpa
        }
        prometheus :9153
        proxy . /etc/resolv.conf
        cache 30
        loop
        reload
        loadbalance
    }
```

More info yo can find [here](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/administer-cluster/dns-custom-nameservers/).

You can verify your env by running:

```
kubectl get cm coredns -n kube-system -o yaml

apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: coredns
  namespace: kube-system
```

and:
kubeadm config view
dns:
  type: CoreDNS

during kubeadm init you should noticed:

```
[addons] Applied essential addon: CoreDNS
```

If you are moving from kube-dns to CoreDNS, make sure to set the CoreDNS `feature gate` to **true** during an upgrade. For example, here is what a v1.11.0 upgrade would look like:
`kubeadm upgrade apply v1.11.0 --feature-gates=CoreDNS=true`

> In Kubernetes version 1.13 and later the CoreDNS feature gate is removed and CoreDNS is used by default. More information [here](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/administer-cluster/coredns/).

You can see if your coredns pod is working properly by running:

```
kubectl logs <your coredns pod> -n kube-system
.:53
2019-05-02T13:32:41.438Z [INFO] CoreDNS-1.3.1
CoreDNS-1.3.1
.
.
```

Comment: Ok, I will load above config for coreDns and will let you know whether it works or not. Thanks a lot for response.

Comment: @Hank, Everything was setup correctly by default, There was a misunderstanding my me on calling services between pods. I have updated my question with answer. Thanks for your help in debugging.

Comment: by running command "kubectl logs <your coredns pod> -n kube-system" , I am getting logs - [WARNING] No files matching import glob pattern: custom/*.server
[WARNING] No files matching import glob pattern: custom/*.override
[WARNING] No files matching import glob pattern: custom/*.server
[WARNING] No files matching import glob pattern: custom/*.override
[WARNING] No files matching import glob pattern: custom/*.server
[WARNING] No files matching import glob pattern: custom/*.override
[WARNING] No files matching import glob pattern: custom/*.server

Comment: Can anyone help me to understand this? is it ever working or not ? Can I redeploy coredns pod? will redeploying coredns pod affect my current deployments?